# Plot a line with varying thickness

Tags: matlab, plot, visualization, matlab-figure

I would like to plot a line in 3D with varying thickness using Matlab. Is it possible to do that (i.e. one line)?
So far I'm able to plot a line in 3D with fixed thickness, e.g.:

```
 path_width = 5;
 plot3(path(:,1), path(:,2), path(:,3), '-', 'LineWidth', path_width);
```

Ideally, I would like that the thickness of the line changes as it is drawn. I have a vector (`path_widths`) containing the thickness that I would like to display for each point in the line. Any suggestions are most welcome

Comment: I doubt it is possible. You should split line into segments and specify width for each segment separately.

Comment: Yep - you'll have to split your line. I'd propose to put all segments into a `hggroup`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not ideal but what about this:

```
hold on
for k = 1:size(path,1)
    plot3(path(k,1), path(k,2), path(k,3), 'o', 'LineWidth', path_widths(k));
end
```

Or else maybe:

```
hold on
for k = 1:size(path,1)-1
    plot3(path(k:k+1,1), path(k:k+1,2), path(k:k+1,3), '-', 'LineWidth', path_widths(k));
end
```